# VM Exception: invalid JUMP when I call a second function

Tags: solidity, remix, bad-jump

I'm experimenting with 
[Solidity Browser](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.1+commit.4fc6fc2c.js)

Here is my  contract code:

```
contract Test {

    mapping (address => uint256) weismap;

    function bet(uint vote) payable returns (uint256 weis) {
        if (msg.value==0) throw;
        weismap[msg.sender]= msg.value;
        return  weismap[msg.sender];
    }

    function test()  returns (uint myVote)  {
           return 1;
    }
}
```

If I set as transaction value **1**

[image: I set as transaction value at 1]

,create the contract and call the function bet with 1 as parameter

the function is run successfully.

If after that,  I call the test() function I get

> VM Exception: invalid JUMP

Any idea, about what's wrong?

Comment: When you put 1 in the browser, it is understood as 1 ether, not 1 wei.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I don't understand what it has to do with error. Besides msg.value is in wei. Are you sure that is relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `constant` keyword to the `test()` function like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Test {
    mapping (address => uint256) weismap;

    function bet(uint vote) payable returns (uint256 weis) {
        if (msg.value==0) 
            throw;
        weismap[msg.sender]= msg.value;
        return  weismap[msg.sender];
    }

    function test() constant returns (uint myVote)  {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Calling `bet(...)` with the value 2. Note that I'm sending 2 ethers as well with the transaction:

[image]

Now I call `test()` **AND I've left the value 2**. This call to `test()` fails as the constant function is being called as a transaction, not a read of the values off the blockchain:

[image]

If I call `test()` **AND I've set value to blank**, this call to `test()` succeeds as the constant function is being called as a read of the values off the blockchain:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it fails. Have you tried it out yourself?Does it work?

Comment: Yup. Tried it in browser-solidity with local `geth 1.4.11-stable`. Answer updated with more details.

Comment: Yes but you didn't call bet. Could you try this please? First you set the transaction value. Then call bet with let's say 2. Then test. Does it work? Thanks