# Explain the invalid JUMP error

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-debugging, testrpc, bad-jump

There are a number of questions relating to the `invalid JUMP` error.

I get this when debugging a solidiy contract on the testrpc with geth command line:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid JUMP at 3802e3b6eefb98
150918c4ddfaabf93c18d6c41aaa2682c5cdbc0a9a9a6a2853/cb611bab0cd7c4f21f7cb0b91ad45
f1330995289:13717
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at web3.js:4055:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4141:16
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

**Can you explain the invlid JUMP error** - what is going wrong at the Virtual Machine opcode level?

**What approach should you use when finding the source of such errors?**

Is this error unique to go-ethereum?

EDIT:

The question is answered here:

[What does a "bad JUMPDEST" error mean?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/694/what-does-a-bad-jumpdest-error-mean)

**What is the distinction, if any, between the above `invlaid JUMP` and that question's `bad JUMPDEST`?**

Other questions:

[oraclize 'VM Exception: invalid JUMP'](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9900/oraclize-vm-exception-invalid-jump)

[VM Exception: invalid JUMP when I call a second function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8630/vm-exception-invalid-jump-when-i-call-a-second-function)

[invalid JUMP after upgrading truffle & testrpc](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9329/invalid-jump-after-upgrading-truffle-testrpc)

[Invalid jump destination error when attempting to transfer The DAO tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/invalid-jump-destination-error-when-attempting-to-transfer-the-dao-tokens)

Comment: That's what I was thinking.

Comment: @eth yes that's a good answer. I'm guessing "invalid JUMP" is geth's wrapper for "bad JUMPDEST" in that question?

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually *testrpc*'s error message. If a transaction throws in geth, it'll treat it as an out-of-gas error and won't tell you. (This is because it technically is an out-of-gas error.)

Unfortunately there's not many current debugging tools. [Browser-Solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) has one. My own method of debugging this kind of is rather shotgun-y. Slowly comment/return early until you don't get an invalid JUMP. If you've commented the whole function, it might be a function being paid without being `payable`.